# Does 'null', 'last_insert_id()', 'true' etc need prepared statements even if they aren't actually User Input?

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, user-input

I do not understand why insert statements such as these

```
INSERT INTO users (id) VALUES (null); //trick to generate a row with default values
INSERT INTO user_reputation (id) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

will require prepared statements?

They are not actually user input, when a user registers I execute these statements inside a transaction. Is it correct to pass them without preparing?

Comment: The general rule when working with databases use prepared statements **always** even if you know the the data is safe **no exceptions**.. what happens if the query is changed with user controled input and you forget to rewrite the code into using prepare?? Trust me it’s a mistake which is easy made..

Comment: They don't *require* prepared statements. It's just the prepared statement police being paranoid again.

Comment: @Vatev XD so technically it's okay, but it's not going by the book.

Comment: @mslilafowler it will work fine (assuming your api allows it of course). Depending on whose book you are subscribed to it may or may not be OK. Playing well with others  is also important.

Comment: That's a good point. Most code after all is a contributed effort from the beginning. Thanks :)